# Python oauth2client async

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, oauth2client, google-cloud-python

I am fighting with **tornado** and the official python **oauth2client**, **gcloud**... modules.

These modules *accept an alternate http client* passed with http=, as long as it has a method called `request` which can be called by any of these libraries, whenever an http request must be sent to google and/or to renew the access tokens using the refresh tokens.

I have created a simple class which has a `self.client = AsyncHttpClient()`
Then in its `request` method, returns `self.client.fetch(...)`

My goal is to be able to `yield` any of these libraries calls, so that tornado will execute them in **asynchronously**.

The thing is that they are highly dependant on what the default client - set to httplib2.Http() returns: (response, content)

I am really stuck and cannot find a clean way of making this async

If anyone already found a way, please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have successfully implemented de authentication handler and am storing the tokens into my DB and am setting some secure cookies to know who the user is and if his session is valid. My issue now is not to have to write my own async methods to access google store, google drive, calendar, email... but kind of hack the part of these official libs which really blocks (http requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These libraries do not support asynchronous. The porting process is not always easy.

**oauth2client**

Depending on what you want to do maybe [Tornado's `GoogleOAuth2Mixin`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/auth.py#L840) or [tornado-alf](https://github.com/globocom/tornado-alf) will be enough.

**gcloud**

Since I am not aware of any Tornado/asyncio implementation of `gcloud-python`, so you could:

- you may write it yourself. Again it's not simple transport change of `Connection.http` or `request`, all the stuff around must be able to use/yield future/coroutines.
- wrap it in `ThreadPoolExecutor` (as @Apero mentioned). This is high level API, so any nested api calls within that yield will be executed in same thread (not using the pool). It could work well.
- external app (with `ProcessPoolExecutor` or `Popen`).

When I had similar problem with AWS couple years ago, I've ended up with executing, asynchronously, CLI ([Tornado + subprocess.Popen](https://gist.github.com/FZambia/5756470) + some cli (awscli, or boto based)) and simple cases (like S3, basic EC2 operations) with plain AsyncHTTPClient.

Comment: I just found this article, maybe I could implement this: http://blog.trukhanov.net/Running-synchronous-code-on-tornado-asynchronously/

Comment: Or do some monkey patching of the libs but I'd rather not

Comment: I've edited answer to your point. Of course you have right, ThreadPoolExecutor is an option, it is not time-consuming, might be a bit more difficult  to scale on high traffic services.